# Differential privacy with strong composition under k-mechanisms with different (ε, δ)-DP bounds

Tags: data-privacy, differential-privacy

The overall DP under the strong composition theorem for k-mechanisms is ($\epsilon \sqrt{k log(1/\delta)}$, k$\delta$) such that each individual mechanism has ($\epsilon, \delta$)-DP.

But what if say, 25% of the total k-mechanisms have $(\epsilon_1, \delta_1)$-DP, while the remaining 75% mechanisms have $(\epsilon_2, \delta_2)$-DP. What would the overall DP be under the rules of strong composition in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you would need to use the optimal composition theorem of Murtagh and Vahdan (see theorem 1.4 of [Concurrent Composition of Differential Privacy by Vadhan and Wang](https://privacytools.seas.harvard.edu/files/privacytools/files/tcc_21_-_2021-1196.pdf) for example).

This says that the mechanisms can be combined into an $(\epsilon_g,\delta_g)$ mechanism whenever $\epsilon_g\ge 0$ satisfies
$$(1+\exp(\epsilon_1))^{-0.25k}(1+\exp(\epsilon_2))^{-0.75k}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{0.25k}\sum_{j=0}^{0.75k}\binom{0.25 k}i\binom{0.75 k}j\mathrm{max}\left(\exp(i\epsilon_1+j\epsilon_2)-\exp(\epsilon_g+(0.25k-i)\epsilon_1+(0.75k-j)\epsilon_2)\right)\right)\le 1-\frac{1-\delta_g}{(1-\delta_1)^{0.25k}(1-\delta_2)^{0.75k}}.$$